# problema al filtrar un jtable en java con netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

mi problema es que filtro el jtable, y al seleccionar la fila eta se envia a unos textfile pero no es la fila que seleccione sino la primera, osea tengo 3 filas, filtro la 3 y cuando la selecciono es como si seleccionara la primera porque los datos que llegan al textfile son de la primera fila y no de la que filtre.
sin filtrar el jtable presiono una fila y efectivamenteme vota los datos ue son, pero cuando la filtro y dejo una sola fila hay es el problema.
MI CODIGO ES EL SIGUIENTE ayudaaaaaaaaaa

```
private void tblSeguimientoMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                            
    if(evt.getClickCount()==1){
        JTable receptor=(JTable)evt.getSource();
        txtID.setText(receptor.getModel().getValueAt(receptor.getSelectedRow(),0).toString());
        txtUsuario.setText(receptor.getModel().getValueAt(receptor.getSelectedRow(),1).toString());
        txtIdentificacion.setText(receptor.getModel().getValueAt(receptor.getSelectedRow(),2).toString());
        txtFecha.setText(receptor.getModel().getValueAt(receptor.getSelectedRow(),3).toString());
        txtCodificacion.setText(receptor.getModel().getValueAt(receptor.getSelectedRow(),4).toString());
        txaAnalisisDesc.setText(receptor.getModel().getValueAt(receptor.getSelectedRow(),5).toString());
        txaSeguimiento.setText(receptor.getModel().getValueAt(receptor.getSelectedRow(),6).toString());
        txaCompromiso.setText(receptor.getModel().getValueAt(receptor.getSelectedRow(),7).toString());
        txtRealizado.setText(receptor.getModel().getValueAt(receptor.getSelectedRow(),8).toString());
        txtValido.setText(receptor.getModel().getValueAt(receptor.getSelectedRow(),9).toString());
        txtNumeroSeguimiento.setText(receptor.getModel().getValueAt(receptor.getSelectedRow(),10).toString());
        txtCorreoInstitucional.setText(receptor.getModel().getValueAt(receptor.getSelectedRow(),11).toString());
        txtCelular.setText(receptor.getModel().getValueAt(receptor.getSelectedRow(),12).toString());
        txtAre.setText(receptor.getModel().getValueAt(receptor.getSelectedRow(),13).toString());
    }
```

}

y este es el otro
TableRowSorter trs;
private void txtFiltroKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {

```
    txtFiltro.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {

            trs.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter( "(?i)" + txtFiltro.getText(),2,8,9,10,13));
        }

    });
    trs = new TableRowSorter(modelo);
    tblSeguimiento.setRowSorter(trs);
}
```

Comment: El código que muestras es sólo la parte donde filtras la tabla. Muestra el evento MouseClicked.